# Duplicate File Exception when using RxAndroid with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am trying to use Retrofit with RxAndroid, so I imported the the required dependencies as shown below. but whn I run the App, I receive the following
error.:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
File1: C:\Users\PC-Amryi\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex\rxjava\1.1.9\e4362e62f1ba92e360b197d6d7ffae67e5ecae9a\rxjava-1.1.9.jar
File2: C:\Users\PC-Amryi\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex.rxjava2\rxjava\2.0.0\5151c737c01616c372c3d00ab145868ede10e826\rxjava-2.0.0.jar
```

to solve this issue I tried to use different RxAndroid and RxJava libs as follows:

```
//RxJava and RxAndroid
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'
//compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

//compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
//compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

but I still get the same error

Please have a look at the gradle file poted below, and please help me to solve it

**gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pc_amr.rxretrofit_1"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    //to enable Java-8
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//RxJava and RxAndroid
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'
//compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

//compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
//compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.solidfire.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson-parent:2.8.1'
compile 'com.solidfire.code.gson:gson-parent:2.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"

compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2"
```

There's no need to exclude meta informations by using matching versions.